# detect hashtag and handles in a text under Android

Tags: java, android, twitter

I'm writing an app which is twitter like. currently I'm display  tweets but only detect the URL link. I'm using the code below:

```
import android.text.Html;
tweet.setText(Html.fromHtml(str_tweets));
```

Using this, the text displayed showing the html tag and "allow" to click on it.

I'm trying to do the same but by also detecting hashtag # and handles @

The goal is to display the profile when click @ and associated post when click on #

I don't really know the best way to make or almost the smarter one.

Any idea ? Any Api from twitter allowing this ??

Thanks